# JNI issue on Linux: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, java-native-interface

I've seen this question on here, tried the proposed fixes, but no success so far for me. I have quite some Java experience, but JNI is a long time ago, never did it on Linux though...

I'm trying to get a simple HelloWorld JNI app running on Linux.

Small java file:

```java
class HelloWorld {

    private native void print();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new HelloWorld().print();
    }

    static {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }

}
```

Small C file:

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return;
}
```

compiled the C file by:

```
gcc -shared -Wall -fPIC HelloWorld.c -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.3/include/ -o libHelloWorld.so
```

Run the app by:

```
java HelloWorld
```

or

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/nxp40954/jnitesting/. HelloWorld
```

But no good, getting a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/nxp40954/jnitesting/libHelloWorld.so: /home/nxp40954/jnitesting/libHelloWorld.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Strange, because there is actually a `/home/nxp40954/jnitesting/libHelloWorld.so` file.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 14):

execute this way:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
java HelloWorld
```

The java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when the .so file cannot be loaded. 
The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable points extra location to look for the *.so files.

I'm on 32bit ubuntu with sun java. I was compiling this way:

```
gcc -shared -Wall -fPIC HelloWorld.c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/linux -o libHelloWorld.so
```

Comment: Yes, I know that libs should go the path that's defined by LD_LIBRARY_PATH, "." is also in there, and even by using the -Djava.library.path=/home/nxp40954/jnitesting I explicitly define where the libHelloWorld.so is located, but I still get this "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: I compiled your code and it works for me. Can you try to do it all in one directory and use "." ? BTW, what java are you using? Waht OS?

Answer (score 5):

Your example worked for me on a 32-bit Linux installation.

Is your shared library compiled as a 32-bit or 64-bit shared library?  Check with command `file libHelloWorld.so`.  If your shared library is 64-bit then you need to give command line option `-d64` when starting Java so that Java can load the 64-bit shared library.

If your shared library is 32-bit then perhaps the Java option `-d32` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks man! Should have thought about that. No 64-bit JVM support, but the lib was 64-bit. Added the -m32 parameter to gcc, all ok not. Thanks!

Comment: On the off-chance this doesn't work for you like me, make sure you specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable as per Michal's answer instead of Java's `java.library.path`. This is because if your linked library needs to access another linked library it will not be able to find it since it doesn't know about `java.library.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification on `java.library.path` and system path:

java.library.path is a JVM-Variable which can be set - e.g. - by the command line parameter

```
-Djava.library.path=xy
```

DLL's (on windows) and so's (on linux) which are loaded by the java call `loadLibrary()` must be located in the java.library.path. If it is loaded via JNI it must be located in the system path.

If such a linked library loads another linked library, latter must be found in the system path. In Windows the system path is resolved against the `PATH` environment variable, in linux it's the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (for linked libraries).

Another point to ensure in linux: Verify that the linked library has executable permissions for the current user. Usually a

```
sudo chmod 755 myLinkedLib
```

does the trick.