# JNI on Linux [JDK] error

Tags: java, c, linux

I started with this file:

koko.java

ran these commands:

```
javac koko.java 
javah koko
(made the c file here)
gcc -/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_18/include -I/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_18/include/solaris -shared -fpic -o koko.so koko.c
java -Djava.library.path=. koko
```

But then I got an error stating:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home04/g/my_username/libkoko.so: ld.so.1: java: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
at ...
at ...
.
.
at koko.<clinit>(koko.java:7)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think this post might hold the key (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284129/jni-issue-on-linux-cannot-open-shared-object-file). Look at the last answer regarding the -d32 option.

Comment: didn't work but Thanks anyways

Comment: Worth a try I guess. Thanks for looking into it.