# UnsatisfiedLinkError exception when lib is explicitly declared

Tags: rhel, java, shared-libraries

Trying to execute my Java app yields a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception when the *libmysqlclient.so.18* can not be found, even when it is explicitly declared in **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, **-Djava.library.path** and **/etc/ld.so.conf**

### PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

I am trying to make use of pcap4j (https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j), a Java wrapper for libpcap, so I can sniff packets on my machine NIFs from a Java application.
As libpcap requires superuser privileges to perform this task, I have to somehow give the non-privileged user executing this app the capacity of accessing the NIFs.

The maintainer of pcap4j suggests granting capabilities `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN` to the java command as follow:
`setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /path/to/java`

Due to implementation limitations I am constrained as follow:

- Avoid giving sudo access to the non-privileged user due to security policies. The same reasoning could be applied to granting above
  mentioned capabilities to the java command  (do not know if
  capability grantings are given per user/command pair), but, from my
  relatively scarce knowledge about security, the latter option looks
  like a more delimited permission granting method for what I want to
  achieve (solutions are welcome too should an alternative permission
  granting method looks more suitable for my purpose), and given that
  the pcapj4 developer, a likely more experienced professional, advices
  so,  I have followed the capability granting path.
- User must be able to execute the app without being password-prompted
- Permission granting must be done only once, e.g. when creating the user for the first time.

After granting `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capabilites to the java command, the problem arose. I am getting the following exception when executing my app:

```
Error creating entity
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /path/to/app/lib/libxpherejava.so: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

### DETAILS

**JAVA:** java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8

**OS:** Linux user-me 3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 15 17:57:37 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)]

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH** contains an explicit path to the not found library:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/lwp:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so:/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is passed to the JVM by making use of **java.library.path**:

```
exec java
-XshowSettings:properties 
-Djava.library.path=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
-d64
...
```

The **"-XshowSettings:properties"** provides me with the following output when the java command is executed:

```
java.library.path =
        /path/to/app/lib
        /path/to/app/lib/glib-2.0
        /usr/lib/lwp
        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
        /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

where `/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18` is a symlink to `/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0`

Seems like JVM (or whatever entity is requesting access to *libmysqlclient.so.18* from *libxpherejava.so*) does not find *libmysqlclient.so.18*, even when its path is explicitly provided to
the java.library.path and the file DOES exist.

With LD_LIBRARY_PATH containing the path to libmysqlclient.so.18 (/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18), issuing **ldd of libxpherejava.so** yields that libmysqlclient.so.18 can not be found

```
[user@user-me log]$ ldd /path/to/app/lib/libxpherejava.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe1a73d000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fd727df4000)
        libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fd727b83000)
        libxphereS.so => /path/to/app/lib/libxphereS.so (0x00007fd727973000)
        libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd72775d000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fd727543000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd727327000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd727025000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd726d11000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd726944000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd726740000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fd7264f3000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fd72620b000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fd726007000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fd725dd4000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd728718000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fd725b72000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fd725964000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fd725760000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fd725547000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fd725320000)
```

This is the content of **ld.so.conf**:

```
[user@user-me lib]$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
/path/to/app/lib/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

Both **libs are 64-bit** compiled:

```
[user@user-me lib]$ file libxpherejava.so
libxpherejava.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=82e1c673e732eb2d3770883b14facf3eff091243, not stripped
[user@user-me lib]$ file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18: symbolic link to libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0'
[user@user-me lib]$ file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=79978c5f4fb259a5a146614e260ea0720dd31d3b, stripped
```

A **strace** over the script that executes the "exec java" command yields this --> https://dumpz.org/aGHQpNk9Znmk

### RELATED QUESTIONS

- [JNI issue on Linux: cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284129/jni-issue-on-linux-cannot-open-shared-object-file) --> Libs are 64-bit and LD_LIBRARY_PATH explicitly contains the path to the problematic lib
- https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/issues/63 --> pcap4j developer answer to a similar problem (solution applied to my environment. Error solved, but the current one arose right after)
- http://blog.tinola.com/?e=7 --> Post about capability granting flaws that could explain all this tweaking

**Does anyone know why is *libmysqlclient.so.18* not being found?**

Comment: I would hazard a guess that a privileged program will ignore `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. (I'd certainly hope it would.)

Comment: @roaima you are correct, `man ld-linux` explains this explicitly: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH <..> This variable is ignored in secure-execution mode.`, and the description of secure-execution mode states the following: `A binary is executed in secure-execution mode if the AT_SECURE entry in the auxiliary vector (see getauxval(3)) has a nonzero value. This entry may have a nonzero value for various reasons, including: <...> A process with a non-root user ID executed a binary that conferred capabilities to the process.`

Comment: @DanilaKiver nice research. Do you want to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @DanilaKiver following your reasoning, I have passed the library as -Djava.library.path=/path/to/app/lib:/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18, without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It still fails on finding the lib, same exception arises.

Comment: @adrikayak, a little clarification: Java in your case explicitly loads only the `libxpherejava.so` library by calling `dlopen()` function internally (thus passing the control to the linker, `ld-linux`). This is the only place here which is influenced by `java.library.path` (which is recognized only by Java itself). The problem is that all the dependencies of the library being loaded are handled by the linker, which does not know anything about `java.library.path` - it knows only its own `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and has its own rules regarding it (see my previous comments).

Comment: @DanilaKiver Understood. I think I found a way out: creating a symlink to the problematic library `libmysqlclient.so.18` under `/usr/lib64`. The exception is gone. If no further comments are added, I will post it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a symlink to the problematic library `libmysqlclient.so.18` under `/usr/lib64` solves the problem. The exception is gone.